# Media Center with UI similar to Popcorn Time

Tags: osx, media-player, media-manager

### I like the UI of [Popcorn Time](http://www.time4popcorn.eu/) a lot.

I'm looking for a program with a similar UI, but which uses local files instead of torrents (scans directories for files, gets information about them from the internet and displays them in a Popcorn Time-ish UI).
**It has to support Mac OS X.**

Does anyone know which program can do this?

---

PS: The kind of UI I am looking for:
[image: UI]

Comment: Just to be clear, you have movies and/or tv-shows stored locally, which you want to display like Popcorn Time does?

Comment: Yes, that's it nidunc !

Answer (score 3):

## I'd advise [XBMC](http://xbmc.org).

**It scans local files (movies, episodes or music), 'scrapes' them for information (gets information about them from various websites), and displays them in a nice interface.**

Examples of its default look:
[image: Home screen]
<sup>*Home Screen*</sup>

[image: TV-Shows view]
<sup>*TV-Shows view*</sup>

There are multiple layouts to choose from, if the default doesn't satisfy you.
And if you want to give it a completely new look, there are a lot of skins that you can install to make it look more to your liking.
**But that isn't all...**

#### There are hundreds of apps and extensions to further customize XBMC. Think of a Youtube app, an app to watch live TV via internet, a µtorrent remote...

<strike>At the moment the website is temporarily down, but you can still download from here: http://mirrors.xbmc.org/releases/
(I'd advise downloading the latest version, xbmc-13.0-Gotham_rc1-x86_64.dmg - go to "osx" --> "x86_64")</strike>

#### The website is up, and [a stable 13.0 has been released](http://xbmc.org/xbmc-13-0-gotham-rises/).

#### However, some bugs were detected afterwards, so [there's also a 13.1-RC1 now](http://xbmc.org/xbmc-13-1-gotham-rc1/).

***It supports Mac OS X, Windows and Linux***

*Lastly, you can use it in windowed mode and fullscreen mode - use <kbd>\</kbd> to switch between the two. (on Windows, I don't know about Mac...)*

Comment: btw, if you're thinking "That doesn't look like Popcorn Time", you're right. But I still suggest XBMC because there are a lot of skins for it, and some of them may look like Popcorn Time - or even better!

Comment: Thanks nidunc ! To be honnest, this is the first software I tried, but it is quite heavy and it does not supports windowed mode correctly... But I will look further for some mods ;)

Comment: Yeah, it is quite big. Although I do think they've optimized things a bit in the newest release (13.0 Gotham).
The issue with windowed mode could be because of the way Mac OS X is built - on Windows it works fine

Comment: And there's also 13.1 now - LET'S FIX SOME BUGS